Approximating 4D hyperspheres using tetrahedrons
In 3D graphics, it is common to approximate surfaces of objects using triangles. For example, a sphere can be approximated using an icosahedron. This icosahedron can have its faces subdivided, meaning turn each triangle into 4 smaller triangles, and then have the new vertices normalized to a unit radius in order to improve the approximation.
In 4D, the equivalent of an icosahedron is the 600-cell, which is composed of 600 tetrahedral cells that form a 3D surface surrounding a 4D area. However, subdividing a 600-cell would be tricky, since as far as I know, tetrahedras cannot be subdivided into smaller tetrahedras with all of the smaller tetrahedras being similar to each other.
What are some mathematical techniques for approximating a 4D hypersphere using tetrahedra? Is the best approach to start with a 600-cell and subdividing it somehow, or are there other approaches?

Barycentric subdivision works in all dimensions, although starting with a regular tetrahedron the results are not regular tetrahedra. You can see pictures here: https://www.google.com/search?q=barycentric+subdivision+tetrahedron

Another idea: chop off the corners of the tetrahedron so that a regular octahedron remains (rectification), and divide the octahedron by adding a vertex in the center and slicing along the three squares formed by its edges, producing 8 more tetrahedra (which aren't quite regular as they have 3 right-triangular faces).

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3560231/what-are-some-nice-high-resolution-tessellations-of-s3
